# Tool for generating control flow in Java

Tags: java, controls, control-flow

I need a tool for generating control flow in java, but not a visual draw, something that I can work with like with path conditions or so.
Anyone ?

Comment: Err, "control flow"? "path conditions"? Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t see your comments. I think I´ve elaborated in my comment of the first answer. Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To future record, what I´ve found that best suits to my needs is Soot.

http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/

Answer (score 3):

The [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/) can do that, at the JVM-bytecode level. See *Method Analysis* and *Control ﬂow analyses* in http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf (page 121).

Comment: Thank you! I think ASM is the type of thing I need. Do you know what is the usual code representation of the graph? Is just like a tree of basic blocks, or it has some information about the conditions? For example in an if/else we 1 condition and 2 basic blocks. The condition is present in the graph ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to see the conditions (compare, lower-than tests, test). Look at the PDF and the site, there is example code in it.

Comment: @arnaud576875 the link you share does not open, this is the updated link i guess: http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf

Comment: This is a very vague answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Atlas](http://www.ensoftcorp.com/atlas/) is an Eclipse plugin that enables program analysis. It has a querable graph database that includes the control flow graph (as well as data flow and other relationships).

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this is what you were looking for http://www.jboss.org/jbpm